# Comparison of string with array in loop

Tags: arrays, string, batch-file, cmd, string-comparison

I am trying to come up with a list of non-recognized devices connected to a wireless network. I am trying to compare those based on MAC addresses (assuming all devices are 'visible' and no one has a hidden or bouncing MAC address) and I have set of those devices in an array which are allowed.

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 ^| find "MAC Address"
```

This gives me a list of all MAC Addresses connected to the default gateway. What would be the easiest way to compare the output of the above with those which are "acceptable" and display the one which are not.

Here is how far I have reached:

```
@echo off
set all_apps="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" "yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy" "zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz"
set "connected="
set "unauthorized="
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 ^| find "MAC Address"') do call set connected="%%a" %%connected%%

echo duplicates:
   for %%a in (%all_apps%) do (
      for %%b in (%connected%) do (
         if "%%~a"=="%%~b" echo %%~b
      )
   )
pause

REM echo %connected% "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" "aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"
```

Here "all_apps" is an array of all acceptable MAC Addresses and "connected" should contain a list of all devices connected. I am able to find out the duplicated ones but not the ones which are not authorized or expected.

Comment: Show us a sample of the output `nmap` is providing for you, as well as your expected duplicate list and content of `connected` and `unauthorized` given that `nmap` output. Disguise the data if required. `nmap` for me is not a recognised command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a little more logic to see when the address is not in the list. This is untested, but it might look like:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo duplicates:
   for %%a in (%all_apps%) do (
      SET "FOUND=false"
      for %%b in (%connected%) do (
         if "%%~a"=="%%~b" echo %%~b
         SET "FOUND=true"
      )
      IF !FOUND! NEQ "true" (ECHO %%~b NOT RECOGNIZED)
   )
```